# Pass Object into class that extends JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtable, observers

I need help with passing an Object from one class to another that extends JFrame, whenever that method is called. So far this is what I have. I need to pass the added circle to the NodeTracker class and make sure it displays the added object.

```
public class Nodes
{
   ArrayList<Circle> circles;
   ArrayList<Squares> squares;

   public Node()
   {
       circles = new ArrayList<Circles>();
       squares = new ArrayList<Squares>();
   }

   public void addCircle(Circle c)
   {
       circles.add(c);
       // Here I want to implement a method that allows me to pass "c"
       // to the NodeTracker
   }

}

// All I have so far that opens a blank table.
public class NodeTracker extends JFrame 
{

    private JPanel topPanel;
    private JTable table;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;

    public NodeTracker()
    {
        setTitle("Node Tracker");
        setSize(700, 700);

        topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        getContentPane().add(topPanel);

        String columns[] = { "Color", "Radius" };

        String data[][] =
        {
            //whenever added, would update
            //{circle.color, circle.radius},
            //{circle.color, circle.radius}
        };

        table = new JTable(data, columns);

        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        topPanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    //Temporary
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        NodeTracker mainFrame = new NodeTracker();
        mainFrame.setVisible( true );
    }
}
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> // Here I want to implement a method that allows me to pass "c" to the NodeTracker"

No, you don't.  You want to implement an [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html).  `Nodes` shouldn't care who is listening for changes, only that when `addCircle` is called, it will tell them.

This way `NodeTracker` would register an interest in `Nodes` to be told when a circle is added and would then be able to respond to in some meaningful fashion

This is a pretty key concept in Swing and is implemented through it's "listener" API

Start by defining a `interface` which describes the events that the `Nodes` class will generate

```
public interface NodesListener {
    public void nodesCircleWasAdded(Nodes source, Circle circle);
}
```

Next, add support for the new listener into `Nodes`, allowing other classes to register/deregister interest and for actually triggering the events

```
public class Nodes {

    ArrayList<Circle> circles;
    ArrayList<Squares> squares;
    private List<NodesListener> listeners;

    public Nodes() {
        circles = new ArrayList<Circles>();
        squares = new ArrayList<Squares>();
        listeners = new ArrayList<>(25);
    }

    public void addNodesListener(NodesListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void addCircle(Circle c) {
        circles.add(c);
        for (NodesListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.nodesCircleWasAdded(this, c);
        }
    }

}
```

Finally, create an instance of `Nodes` or pass a pre-existing instance to the class and register your interest in getting notifications from it...

```
public class NodeTracker extends JFrame {

    private JPanel topPanel;
    private JTable table;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private Nodes nodes;

    public NodeTracker() {
        setTitle("Node Tracker");
        setSize(700, 700);

        nodes = new Nodes();
        nodes.addNodesListener(new NodesListener() {
            @Override
            public void nodesCircleWasAdded(Nodes source, Circle circle) {
                // A circle was added
            }
        });

        topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        getContentPane().add(topPanel);

        String columns[] = {"Color", "Radius"};

        String data[][]
                        = { //whenever added, would update
                        //{circle.color, circle.radius},
                        //{circle.color, circle.radius}
                        };

        table = new JTable(data, columns);

        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        topPanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    //Temporary
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        NodeTracker mainFrame = new NodeTracker();
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: beat me to the punch (again!)!

Comment: Should I create a new class that observes any changes?

Comment: @user287474 That's entirely up to you and your design

Comment: My question to the OP, to @user287474 is **who** calls `addCircle(...)`, and **when** do they call it? What event triggers this call, and with what data? Also this application likely should be made as close to MVC as possible.

Comment: It's called by a message handler. Basically, this framework is supposed to receive shapes from peers and add it to the Node class. And how would I be able to do that? (make it similar to MVC)?

Comment: @user287474 You're not far off a MVC, your `Node` class is already acting like a model.  See [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) for more details

Comment: I'm reading through your code, trying to understand it.. but what's the purpose of you taking in the Node as your parameter to you interface method?

Comment: @user287474 Typically, so you know the source of the event.  Imagine you have multiple instance of an object which are you listening to, for each event you want to take appropriate action based on the source of that event

Comment: @MadProgrammer Okay, that does make sense. So let me reiterate so that you can correct me if I have any misunderstandings. So as soon I call "addCircle()", That not only does it's intended purpose, but it passes the Circle, through the interface and into the Tracker, for me to do whatever I wish with that Object, right?

Comment: @user287474 Basically, passing the `Nodes` and `Circle` when ever `addCircle` is called is simply to make the life of the listener easier, as they don't need to try and then ascertain the context of the event.  I did this purely as a demonstration, your needs might differ

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it.